# authenticating application codebase

Tags: authentication, codebase

So I have been working on a client/server application written in java. At the moment I am looking for a way to verify that the code of the client application has not be changed and then recompiled. I've been searching Google for some time without a lot of success. An educated guess would be to generate a hash value of the client's code during runtime, send it to the server and compare it with a database database entry or a variable. However I am not sure if that is the right way or even how to generate a hash of the codebase during execution in a secure way? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would stop the nefarious user from simply having the client send the correct checksum to the server each time? Nothing.

There is currently no way to completely ensure that software running on a client computer is not running altered software. It's simply not possible to trust their software without asserting control over their hardware and software. Unfortunately, this is a situation where you should focus on software features and quality, something that benefits all users, rather than preventing a few users from hacking your software.